# Can ‘is’ and ‘are’ be used in the same sentence? ‘The conclusion is both are harmful.’

Tags: verbs, verb-agreement

> The conclusion is both are harmful.

My friends told me that you can not use 'is' and 'are' in the same sentence.

Comment: Your friends are wrong. There is one conclusion and two things that are harmful.  The sentence would be clearer with a ’that’: “The conclusion is that both are harmful.”

Comment: But is it wrong ?

Comment: The sentence is correct. 'Both' refers to two elements and takes 'are' for the plural.

Comment: Personally I would insert "that" between "is" and "both" to give "My conclusion is that both are harmful" which would make it a bit easier to read. Otherwise it's correct.

Comment: Using both "is" and "are" means that you _might_ be mixing singular and plural and you should check to make sure, but in this case it's correct.

Comment: A colon would clear things up a lot. Consider "The conclusion is: both are harmful"

Comment: It took me forever to understand the sentence: a "that" or a colon could definitely be added!

Comment: *Can ‘is’ and ‘are’ be used in the same sentence?* -- The rule is “One verb per ***clause***.” The rule is ***not*** “one verb per sentence.” == Compare this single sentence: “The conclusion is [that] the man who ***owned*** the gun that ***was*** the murder weapon ***had left*** the building before the murder ***was*** committed.”

Comment: So, "Is 'are' correct?", you ask?

Comment: @Greybeard **Have** you **considered** that that **could** **be** **improved** by **mentioning** [Modal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_verb), [Auxiliary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_verb) or [Participle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participle) verbs?

Comment: @OP: We're all having fun teasing your friends. They're wrong if they told you that _this_ sentence is incorrect. There are _other_ sentences where you shouldn't use both verbs, and they may have been trying to help you with those mistakes. Even this sentence is _clearer_ if you use a 'that' to separate the subject from the phrase in the predicate.

Comment: @Closers: This question should absolutely not be closed. On the other hand, it obviously belongs at the English Language Learners stack, if that's still a thing.

Comment: Ask your friends to rephrase the sentence so it's correct, from their point of view, then explain the meaning of it.

Comment: This question answers itself.

Comment: @AmagicalFishy that's not a correct use of a colon, because a colon needs to follow a complete sentence. You could edit it to something like "the conclusion is this: both are harmful." But IMO the sentence is fine as it is.

Comment: @Kat You're correct. I wish I could edit my comment.

Comment: Anyone can say "X is wrong". But where are they getting their information from? Should you treat them as an authority? How do they propose "fixing" this sentence? Do they think that either of "The conclusion is both is harmful." or "The conclusion are both are harmful." are correct?

Comment: @Kat no, to wit: sometimes it can be used between a statement and an illustration of that statement (telegraphed or not).

Comment: And honestly the best way to clarify is to enclose the conclusion in quotation marks (since you are, in fact, quoting it, if that was indeed the conclusion).

Answer (score 55):

When in doubt, I find it helpful to simplify the sentence.  Consider these:

> The conclusion is uncertain.
>   The conclusion is final.
>   The conclusion is X.

Clearly, whatever the conclusion is, it's singular and needs a singular verb.

Now let's look at what the actual conclusion is:

> Both are harmful.

Again, clearly, "both" refers to two things and thus requires a plural verb, "are".  You could check that by replacing both:

> Cigarettes and gun battles are harmful.
>   Angry dragons and mean dogs are harmful.

Now, let's take that last *conclusion* example -- *The conclusion is X.* -- and replace X with what it actually is:

> The conclusion is [both are harmful].

When you look at it that way, it becomes clear that the sentence as originally written is indeed correct.

My conclusion **is** that your friends **are** wrong.

Comment: Last conclusion exactly to the point!

Comment: @RogerSinasohn, is there a way to punctuate it to be more clear?  `The conclusion is: both are harmful` etc.?

Comment: I think that @BoldBen's suggestion of inserting "that" -- as in _The conclusion is **that** both are harmful_ -- would go a long way to making it more clear.  It sort of adds a pause, much as the colon would, without being unnatural.

Answer (score 3):

No. No, no, no. Send your friends back a grade.

*Conclusion* is singular. Use *is*.

*Both* is plural. Use *are*.

Answer (score 2):

In relative , noun or adverbial clauses we often face these kinds of sentences. E.g  “Who I am is not important.

Answer (score 1):

You have two ideas together. One is that the conclusion *is* right. The other is that both A and B *are* harmful. You are putting these into one sentence and finding it troublesome.

You are also rushing by with spoken English and leaving out an implied word that explains things.

The conclusion is *that* both are purple.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the way you define what *sentence* means in your context.

If you mean the string between two periods, then yes, a sentence can have an arbitrary number of conjugated verbs, and hence *is* and *are* in one sentence are allowed. For example:

> The weather is fine and all people are happy.

If you consider a sentence to be the part containing subject and conjugated verb (or an infinitive sentence), then it is not possible. Then, the example above must be considered as two sentences that are contactenated.

The example in your question is really a sentence and its subclause - so it is one sentence in the first sense but two sentences in the latter sense. For better readability, there should be a *that* in between:

> The conclusion is that both are harmful.

Comment: *"the part containing subject and conjugated verb "* - Isn't that the definition of a clause? How could you consider that a sentence?

Comment: @wjandrea A clause is a part of sentence that is incomplete on its own.

Comment: Not necessarily. You can have independent clauses, which could be their own sentences but aren't. In your example, `The weather is fine` and `all people are happy` are independent, so you could also write `The weather is fine. All people are happy.`, though it sounds clunky.

Comment: @wjandrea You say it: "Not necessarily." The Oxford definition of what a clause is is so blurry that I find it pretty useless. Many other languages do not have two different words for sentences and clauses although they also distinguish them quite well.

Answer (score 0):

No reason they can't be used in the same sentence, but for the sentence you provided it's incorrect.

The context of the question is "can you use both or only one", so "both" is *a solution* and therefore:

"The conclusion is [the use of] both is harmful."

In the original sentence, "The conclusion is both are harmful.", this is implying that *both* words "is" and "are" are independently harmful, and they are not both harmful.